# How to simplify the following SOP expression in Boolean Algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can anyone help me with the following Boolean Algebra expression?

$Y\hspace{1mm}=\hspace{1mm}\overline{A}B\overline{C}D\hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm}\overline{A}BC\overline{D}\hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm}\overline{A}BCD\hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm}AB\overline{C}D\hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm}ABC\overline{D}\hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm}ABCD$

I have been trying to solve it but I can't seem to the answer which is $BC + BD$. I got this answer using K-Map and I just want to verify it using the Algebraic method. This is what I have been doing

[image: My Method]

Am I doing anything wrong? 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the six products fall into three pairs that differ in only the $A$ literal:
$$(B\overline CD)(A+\overline A)+(BC\overline D)(A+\overline A)+(BCD)(A+\overline A)$$
Since $A+\overline A=1$, this reduces to
$$B\overline CD+BC\overline D+BCD=B(CD+\overline CD+C\overline D)$$
Now
$$CD+\overline CD+C\overline D=C(D+\overline D)+\overline CD=C+\overline CD$$
$$=\overline{\overline C(\overline D+C)}=\overline{\overline C\cdot\overline D}=C+D$$
Eventually we reach the desired result of $B(C+D)$.

Comment: Can you write down the steps for the final step as well? As I couldn't grasp how you got C + D. Rest all good. Thank you for the answer :))

Comment: @Utkarsh There?

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel for the help :))